# SVN server only allows commits when run as root

Tags: server, permissions, services, svn

So as of two days ago I had myself a shiny new SVN server. I set it up for WebDAV with no problems. It wasn't until I tried to host multiple projects that I ran into trouble.

At first, I had all of the project folders in one repository. But then I saw the error in my ways and switched to multiple repositories. Rather than editing the `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default` file with every new project, I selected to use the svnserve daemon.

So, the problem is, I can only make commits from Eclipse when the daemon is run as root. If not, I get a "Permission Denied" error. Any ideas? Here are the directory stats:

```
    drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4096 2011-06-07 09:38 .
    drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 2011-06-05 00:48 ..
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 svn  svn     6 2011-06-06 22:35 all -> repos/
    drw-rw-r-- 6 svn  svn  4096 2011-06-06 13:53 EmpowerView
    drw-rw-r-- 6 svn  svn  4096 2011-06-06 13:54 GoogleVoicemail
    -rw-rw-r-- 2 svn  svn   307 2011-06-07 08:47 passwd
    drw-rw-r-- 6 svn  svn  4096 2011-06-06 13:54 PerlinNoise
    drw-rw-r-- 7 svn  svn  4096 2011-06-05 02:15 repos
    -rw-rw-r-- 3 svn  svn  2278 2011-06-07 08:46 svnserve.conf
```

## EDIT

I tried the suggested re-checkout with the daemon not running as root, and still no cigar. Same permission error.

## EDIT 2

I also tried running the daemon as the user svn, but no such luck. At one point I screwed up my primary group and no longer had sudo privileges! I had to hack into my own server through a buddy's account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're having a classic permission issue. Your repository is possibly located at a location like `/some/dir/repos` with `/some` being `svn` not being able to access `/some` because svn does not own `/some` and:

- `svn` is in the group of `/some`, but the permissions are set like 700
- `svn` is not in the group of `/some` and the permissions are set like 750

In both cases, `svn` cannot descend in `/some` because the execute-bit is missing on `/some`.

Two solutions are possible:

- add the other execute bit to `/some` so the permissions look like 751
- add the group execute bit to `/some` and make sure the user `svn` is a member of the group

You need to check all directories above your repo. So if your path looks like `/i/am/very/long/repos`, you need to check `/i`, `/i/am` till `/i/am/very/long/repos`.

Comment: Simply don't mix up http/webdav and direct file access. If root crippled file rights, do `chown -R www-data:wwdata /path/to/repository` (exchange www-data with your matching user/group).